# Crystal Report: Missing Data in the browse data under Database Fields

Tags: database, oracle, crystal-reports

Can someone help me with this issue in the Crystal Report

I am using Crystal Report 2011 and Oracle database.
My query is to output some columns in 2 different table(A,B). 
After run query, there is 126,978 rows in the result. 
In table A, there are 36 different types. The result shows same 
in the Oracle Sql Development and Crystal Report (126,978 rows).
it also shows 36 different types in the details section. But when I right click 
on that column, there is 23 different types and missing other 13 types.
I tried many ways but without successful (still missing). 
Is there any problem with the software? Data missing hence I cannot create correct
dynamic parameter. If it does not show all 36 different type, then my query possibly 
wrong, but it can show in the details section, then browse data option should show all 36 types right?
Do you have any idea to solve this?

Comment: this is a little hard to follow.. could your problem be related to the SQL crystal is running or in the report design?  You might post the SQL in Database (under the view drop down).  Tell us which table contains the data you need.  Is your dynamic parameter fed by a custom SQL?

Answer (score 0):

See the Crystal Reports help. By default if you use "Browse Data" Crystal will show you only the first 500 unique values of that field.You can change that for the current report by clearing the "Select Distinct Data for Browsing" option in the Report Options.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I clear the "Select Distinct Data for Browsing" but some data is still missing. I resolve this writing another command to have all value I needs, then link to the query. This way all data I need can show up in the dynamic list. Thanks.